# Image cropping in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have an application that uses React and TypeScript.
Recently I have been trying to allow used to crop an image before setting it as their profile picture.

I've chosen to use the `react-easy-crop` package and its `Cropper` component but I've ran into several issues.

Despite this I've got to the point where I'm trying to save the cropped area as a HTML canvas then trigger a `PUT` request that updates the image in the database.

Currently I'm stuck on the canvas functionality. My knowledge of TypeScript is limited and that seems to be the area of issue.

Currently I get this error:

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
index.d.ts(351, 10): An argument for 'props' was not provided.
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7009)
(alias) const Image: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<Omit<React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, "height" | "width" | ... 4 more ... | "srcSet"> & {
    ...;
} & React.RefAttributes<...>>
import Image
```

On this line:

```
const image = new Image();
```

I've tried various sources including their own documentation and it seems their TypeScript demos are very limited. So I thought id ask here.

This is the current setup I have.

A Model popup menu with my button and cropper:

```
        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 flex items-center justify-center">
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-800 opacity-75"></div>

          <div className="w-full sm:w-[600px] rounded border z-10 bg-white mx-2.5 sm:mx-0">
            <div className="mt-3 mx-3 font-bold text-lg text-gray-700">
              Edit Image
            </div>

            {/* Image cropper */}
            <div className="w-full h-[450px] mt-2.5 px-3">
              <Cropper
                image={sessionUser.profilePicture}
                crop={crop}
                zoom={zoom}
                aspect={1}
                onCropChange={setCrop}
                onCropComplete={onCropComplete}
                onZoomChange={setZoom}
                cropShape="round"
                showGrid={false}
                style={{
                  containerStyle: {
                    position: "relative",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    borderRadius: "0.25rem",
                  },
                  cropAreaStyle: {
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: "50%",
                    left: "50%",
                    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
                    border: "1px solid #fff",
                  },
                  mediaStyle: {
                    objectFit: "cover",
                  },
                }}
              />
            </div>

            {/* Zoom slider */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-center my-6 mx-3 sm:mx-6 space-x-6">
              {/* Attribution: https://heroicons.com/ */}
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                strokeWidth="1.5"
                stroke="currentColor"
                className="w-5 h-5"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M2.25 15.75l5.159-5.159a2.25 2.25 0 013.182 0l5.159 5.159m-1.5-1.5l1.409-1.409a2.25 2.25 0 013.182 0l2.909 2.909m-18 3.75h16.5a1.5 1.5 0 001.5-1.5V6a1.5 1.5 0 00-1.5-1.5H3.75A1.5 1.5 0 002.25 6v12a1.5 1.5 0 001.5 1.5zm10.5-11.25h.008v.008h-.008V8.25zm.375 0a.375.375 0 11-.75 0 .375.375 0 01.75 0z"
                />
              </svg>

              <Slider
                value={zoom}
                min={1}
                max={3}
                step={0.1}
                onChange={(e, zoom) => setZoom(zoom as number)}
                sx={{
                  color: "#3B82F6",
                  width: "75%",
                }}
              />

              {/* Attribution: https://heroicons.com/ */}
              <svg
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                strokeWidth="1.5"
                stroke="currentColor"
                className="w-8 h-8"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  d="M2.25 15.75l5.159-5.159a2.25 2.25 0 013.182 0l5.159 5.159m-1.5-1.5l1.409-1.409a2.25 2.25 0 013.182 0l2.909 2.909m-18 3.75h16.5a1.5 1.5 0 001.5-1.5V6a1.5 1.5 0 00-1.5-1.5H3.75A1.5 1.5 0 002.25 6v12a1.5 1.5 0 001.5 1.5zm10.5-11.25h.008v.008h-.008V8.25zm.375 0a.375.375 0 11-.75 0 .375.375 0 01.75 0z"
                />
              </svg>
            </div>

            {/* Save and cancel buttons */}
            <div className="flex items-center justify-end py-4 px-3 space-x-5 bg-gray-100">
              <div
                onClick={() => {
                  setIsEditing(false);
                  setEditingSection("");
                }}
                className="text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 hover:underline hover:cursor-pointer"
              >
                Cancel
              </div>

              <Button
                variant="contained"
                onClick={cropHandler}
                sx={{
                  borderRadius: "0.25rem",
                  textTransform: "none",
                  fontSize: "0.75rem",
                  color: "#fff",
                }}
                className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600" // MUI background color bug workaround
              >
                Save
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

And some states and functions that allow the cropped area to be set and saved:

```
  // Crop image handler
  const cropHandler = () => {
    // If cropped area pixels exist, create base64 of cropped image
    if (croppedAreaPixels) {
      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = sessionUser.profilePicture;
      image.onload = () => {
        const scaleX = image.width / image.naturalWidth;
        const scaleY = image.height / image.naturalHeight;
        canvas.width = croppedAreaPixels.width;
        canvas.height = croppedAreaPixels.height;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        if (ctx) {
          ctx.drawImage(
            image,
            croppedAreaPixels.x * scaleX,
            croppedAreaPixels.y * scaleY,
            croppedAreaPixels.width * scaleX,
            croppedAreaPixels.height * scaleY,
            0,
            0,
            croppedAreaPixels.width,
            croppedAreaPixels.height
          );
        }
        const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        console.log(base64Image);
        // axios
        // .put(`/settings/profile_picture`, {
        //   value: base64Image,
        // })
        // .then((res) => {
        //   setSessionUser({
        //     ...sessionUser,
        //     profilePicture: res.data,
        //   });

        //   setIsEditing(false);
        //   setEditingSection("");
        // });
      };
    }
  };
```

I'm hoping someone can provide me a solution to my current issue or suggest a better method for image cropping in React.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using NextJS? I experienced the same problem as you and it was because import Image from next/image overrides the namespace of vanilla javascript new Image(). If you remove the next/image import, you'll notice that the error goes away for const whatever = new Image();

The nextjs version expects to be given Props and doesnt have a constructor so can't "new" since it's a html tag. The js version is a constructor that may take 0 or 2 variables (width, height)